# Nexus OS authenticate via ssh key

Tags: cisco, ssh, cisco-nx-os

on the catalyst IOS I hadn't had any problems with activating the ssh auth via public key, but on the Nexus OS I can't seem to find the option. Is it even implemented in some NX-OS version?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

In NX OS version 6 the following works:

```
username <your username> sshkey ssh-rsa <your rsa key>
```

You must of course set the access level with, for example for full access

```
username <your usernam> role network-admin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an SSH server key based on your security requirements. The default SSH server key is an RSA key that is generated using 1024 bits.

[Here is the link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/6_x/nx-os/security/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_7000_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide__Release_6-x/b_Cisco_Nexus_7000_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide__Release_6-x_chapter_01000.pdf)

Comment: The given link doesn't works. please check it again.

Comment: Please add relevant details to the answer instead of linking to a document.